# External HDD killing MacBook Air, causing kernel panic attack, then unstoppable shut down mounting HFS+ from a partition on the drive

Tags: macos, partition, external-disk, kernel-panic, ipados

External portable HDD connected to iPad Pro M1 is only displaying 2 of 4 partitions suddenly. When connected to MacBook Air 2015 (running most up to date OS as the model can - maybe Catalina…?), the computer shuts down in a total panic when it tries to `mount_HFS`. It actually killed the Mac, leaving it completely u responsive. Which is why I am trying my iPad Pro.

I still have the error report from the Mac. Here’s a summary:

1. Kernel Panic: This is a critical error that the macOS kernel cannot recover from, leading to a forced restart. The report starts with `panic(cpu 0 caller...)`, indicating the panic's initiation.
2. Journaling File System Error: The message `jnl: do_jnl_io: curlen == 0, offset 0x226e800 len 0` suggests an issue with the HFS+ journaling system. This could imply file system corruption or an error with the drive's ability to read or write data correctly.
3. File System Extension: The kernel extensions in the backtrace, particularly `com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext`, reinforce that the issue is related to the HFS+ file system, which is used by macOS.
4. External HDD Connection: Since this occurred when an external HDD was connected, the panic could be triggered by issues with this external drive, its connection, or compatibility.
5. Process Name: The process `mount_hfs` indicates that the kernel panic occurred while attempting to mount an HFS file system, likely from the external HDD.
6. System and Kernel Information: The report includes specific details about your macOS version (21G630) and the Darwin Kernel Version (21.6.0), which are useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Do you have a question? The drive is malfunctioning.

Comment: @LincD. Clearly — though I'd be disappointed to find a malfunctioning drive could cause a kernel panic…

Comment: @LincD. - I guess I was hoping someone out there might know some way of mounting the drive to properly diagnose and hopefully repair it by somehow isolating it or using the Mac in a safe mode, for example. The drive was my backup for some personally important projects and their documentation and I’d be right pissed if I lost it.

Comment: @gidds - why disappointed? There could be more to it. I had the error report summarised by ChatGPT as it is a little beyond me to understand it comprehensively.

Comment: A malfunctioning drive most certainly can cause kernel panics. See, for example, https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-your-mac-restarts-and-a-message-appears-mchlp2890/mac

Comment: You say that the drive is a backup, but apparently it contains primary data for which you have no backups. In that case, your best chance of recovering anything is to stop messing with it and send it to a recovery service.